Two-dimensional Laplace equation outside a circle
The point of this exercise is to determine the solution to the two dimensional Laplace equation outside a circle of radius $R$ in analogy to the problem outside a sphere.

It is given that the two dimensional equation $$
\nabla^{2}\operatorname{G}\left(\vec{r}, \vec{r}\,'\right) =
\delta\left(\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'\right)
$$ can be solved with
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\ln\left(\frac{\left\vert\,{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}\,\right\vert}{C}\right)\quad
\mbox{where}\quad C > 0.
$$
Determine the Green's function for Dirichlet boundary conditions on the circle.
Consider an infinitely long wire with a constant line charge density $\lambda$ at a distance $D$ from the center of an infinitely long conducting cylinder with radius $R < D$, on whose surface the potential is zero.
The line charge should be parallel to symmetry axis of the cylinder.
What is the potential in the exterior region and the induced surface charge density in this case ?.
Express the solution explicitly in terms of the line charge $\lambda$: Then determine the Green's function.
I am stuck in this question.
I have derived the Dirichlet problem
\begin{align}
\nabla^{2}\Phi\left(r,\phi,z\right) & = -4\pi\lambda\,\delta\left(\phi\right)
\delta\left(r - D\right),\quad
\mbox{for}\ r > R
\\[2mm] \Phi\left(R,\phi,z\right) & = 0 
\end{align}
where the rotation axis of the cylinder lies on the z-axis.
I think
$$
\Phi_{1}\left(r,\phi,z\right) = -2\lambda\ln\left(\,\left\vert\, r
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\left(\phi\right) \\ \sin\left(\phi\right) \end{pmatrix} - D
\begin{pmatrix}
1
\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\,\right\vert\,\right)
$$
solves the Laplace equation, but does not satisfy the boundary conditions.

I was thinking of applying a method similar to the image charge method, but I can't find any adequate function.
Does someone have an idea how to solve this problem ?.

Can you be a bit clearer with the problem? Is the line charge outside the cylinder? Is the distance $D$ from the center of the cylinder or from the exterior? What angle does the line charge make with the cylinder? Can we use image charges or are we supposed to use Green's functions? Please be a little more specific with the problem statement.

"Express the solution explicitly in terms of the line charge $\lambda$. Then determine the Green's function." Does this mean that your solution cannot use the Green's function itself? If that's the case then this is a method of images problem firsthand.

To proceed with the method of images, we use the expressions for the potentials generated by line charges
$$
\Phi(x)=-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{r}{C}\right)
$$
where $C$ is some arbitrary constant. This line charge is placed at some point $D{\bf n}$ in the $2$-D plane parallel to the cylinder, where $\bf n$ is a unit vector. The potential is then
$$
\Phi(x)=-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{|{\bf x}-D{\bf n}|}{C}\right)
$$
Similar to the derivation for a grounded conducting sphere, we assume that an image line charge can be placed inside the cylinder with some charge density $\lambda'$ at a point $d\bf n$ to create zero potential at $|{\bf x}|=R$. The potential combined by the two charges is
$$
\Phi=-\frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\lambda\ln\left(\frac{|{\bf x}-D{\bf n}|}{C_1}\right)+\lambda'\ln\left(\frac{|{\bf x}-d{\bf n}|}{C_2}\right)\right]
$$
Why the difference $C$'s? Because line charges have weird properties regarding their potentials, where the potential cannot go to zero at infinity, and the choice of $C$ simply determines what $0$ is. We leave these alone fro now and will return later.
If ${\bf x}=R{\bf n}'$, meaning that we are evaluating at $|x|=R$, we get
$$
0=\Phi(|{\bf x}|=R)=-\frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{\lambda}{2}\ln\left(\frac{R^2-2RD\cos\gamma+D^2}{C_1^2}\right)+\frac{\lambda'}{2}\ln\left(\frac{R^2-2Rd\cos\gamma+d^2}{C_2^2}\right)\right]
$$
where $\cos\gamma={\bf n}\cdot{\bf n}'$. Simplifying,
$$
\lambda\ln\left(\frac{R^2-2RD\cos\gamma+D^2}{C_1^2}\right)+\lambda'\ln\left(\frac{R^2-2Rd\cos\gamma+d^2}{C_2^2}\right)=0
$$
In order to have this expression be true for any choice of gamma, we can differentiate with respect to $\cos\gamma$ and we must get zero. Letting $z=\cos\gamma$ and differentiating with respect to $z$, we get
$$
-\frac{2RD\lambda}{R^2-2RDz+D^2}-\frac{2Rd\lambda'}{R^2-2Rdz+d^2}=0
$$
Clearing denominators and removing the extra factor of $2R$,
$$
DR^2\lambda-2RDd\lambda z+Dd^2\lambda+dR^2\lambda'-2RDd\lambda'z+D^2d\lambda'=0
$$
This must be identically zero for any $z$, so grouping like terms,
$$
-2RDd(\lambda+\lambda')z+\left(DR^2\lambda+Dd^2\lambda+dR^2\lambda'+D^2d\lambda'\right)=0
$$
The first piece states that $\lambda'=-\lambda$. This may seem strange, but is actually a consequence for the fact that two opposite line charges have equipotentials that form circles, a well known result. From here, substituting $\lambda'=-\lambda$ and removing $\lambda$ gives
$$
DR^2+Dd^2-dR^2-D^2d=0
$$
This is a quadratic equation for $d$ and solutions are
$$
d=\frac{R^2+D^2\pm\sqrt{(R^2+D^2)^2-4D^2R^2}}{2D}=\frac{(R^2+D^2)\pm(R^2-D^2)}{2D}
$$
Our two possible solutions are
$$
d=\frac{R^2}{D},\;\;\;\;d=D
$$
For obvious reasons we scrap $d=D$ and have $d=R^2/D$. Returning to our original potential we then have
$$
\Phi=-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\ln\left(\frac{|{\bf x}-D{\bf n}|}{\left|{\bf x}-\frac{R^2}{D}{\bf n}\right|}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)\right]
$$
This is where our $C$'s come in. We want $\Phi=0$ when $|{\bf x}|=R$, and selecting $C_1$ and $C_2$ to satisfy that comes into play. For example, if ${\bf x}=R{\bf n}$ then
$$
0=\Phi({\bf x}=R{\bf n})=-\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\ln\left(\frac{D-R}{R-\frac{R^2}{D}}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)\right]\implies\ln\left(\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{R}{D}\right)
$$
This gives us our $C$'s.
From here, we want to assemble the Green's function, which we can do by inspection. To do this, we know that the Green's function should be symmetric in both ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf x}'$, so we will massage this expression to look as such. To do this, we use log properties to square the inside and get
$$
\Phi=-\frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{R^2|{\bf x}|^2-2R^2(D{\bf n})\cdot{\bf x}+R^2|D{\bf n}|^2}{|D{\bf n}|^2|{\bf x}|^2-2R^2(D{\bf n})\cdot{\bf x}+R^4}\right)
$$
The charge we pick up is $\lambda\delta({\bf x}-{\bf x'})$ where ${\bf x'}=D{\bf n}$ in this case, so we replace $D{\bf n}\to{\bf x}'$ and remove the factor of $-\frac{\lambda}{\epsilon_0}$ from the front to get
$$
G({\bf x},{\bf x'})=\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\left(\frac{R^2|{\bf x}|^2-2R^2{\bf x}\cdot{\bf x}'+R^2|{\bf x}'|^2}{|{\bf x}|^2|{\bf x}'|^2-2R^2{\bf x}\cdot{\bf x}'+R^4}\right)
$$
(this is correct up to factors of 2 and $\pm$'s, depending on your definition of a Green's function)
If interested, the numerator is a perfect square, so we could write
$$
G({\bf x},{\bf x}')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{R|{\bf x}-{\bf x}'|}{\sqrt{|{\bf x}|^2|{\bf x}'|^2-2R^2{\bf x}\cdot{\bf x}'+R^4}}\right)
$$
And there's your Green's function for infinite line charges in $2$-D with a boundary condition at $|{\bf x}|=R$.
